# css message locator in robotframework

Tags: css, robotframework

Please advice me about to find css message locator in robotframework.
I can not use id cause of change every time when I run test script.
Only Class not change but have a lot of message.
Hence I want to catch the message instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHVyo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY53r.png)

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are trying to ask. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't include links to screenshots of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, you need to select an element based on CSS class. If you need exactly that solution, you can go with CSS locator `css:z-menu-img`, if you are sure that this is the only element with that CSS class in the page.

Otherwise, I propose another solution (as unstable as the others because it can change over time): use XPath. For your case, it can be: `//*[@id="kOIQf6-a"]/span`.